# Why Python returns a False statement when it shouldn't?

Tags: python, equals, modulo

Take this code for example:

```
print 2.0 == 2 #---> returns True

print 12 % 5 #---> returns 2
print ((12.0 / 5) - (12 / 5)) * 5 #---> returns 2.0

print ((12.0 / 5) - (12 / 5)) * 5 == 12 % 5 #---> returns False (What the hell happens here?)
```

Comment: `((12.0 / 5) - (12 / 5)) * 5` isn't `2.0`

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Furthermore, this differs between Python 2 and 3. Python2: `((12.0 / 5) - (12 / 5)) * 5 = 1.9999999999999996`, Python3: `((12.0 / 5) - (12 / 5)) * 5 = 0.0`

Comment: @BrandonInvergo: Use `//`, integer division, on Python 3: `((12.0 / 5) - (12 // 5)) * 5`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ...you learn something new every day...thanks!

Comment: On the major differences between python 2 and 3: in python 3 this raises a `TypeError` because it tries to multiply the return of the `print()`, which is `None`, by `5`.  just thought that was kinda funny.

Comment: @RyanHaining: in Python 3 you'd put the *whole* expression in parenthesis, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the first calculation does not return *exactly* 2.0:

```
>>> ((12.0 / 5) - (12 / 5)) * 5
1.9999999999999996
```

`print` limits floating point display to 12 significant digits only, causing the value to be rounded to 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

@Bakuriu got the long answer in the comment for you.

In short, it's not right at all to perform equality comparison between floating point numbers. Always choose an appropriate epsilon value (error range) to make sure the difference between the desired whole number and calculated results is within your tolerated error range.

Say you set `eps = 1e-5` (error within +/- 0.00001)

Then you can do

`print abs(((12.0 / 5) - (12 / 5)) * 5 - 12 % 5) < eps`

Note: you can also do <=, depends on your precision needs.